# How to fix 'An object reference is required to acces non-static member'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error:

> Assets/PlayerScript.cs(220,35): error CS0120: An object reference is
>   required to access non-static member `Generate.seed'

With this code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(Generate.seed);
}
```

And i declared in Generate.cs:

```
 public int seed;
```

Comment: `someGenerateObject.seed`; or make `seed` static *iff* such is appropriate. Please [search for errors messages next time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=An+object+reference+is+required+to+access+non-static+member)

Comment: well you either use an object reference ... to an instance of `Generate` or make `seed` a `public static int seed`

Comment: "seed" is not a static Member of the class "Generate". You try to use it like a Static Member. Either make it a static member, or stop using it like one. You need to learn the difference between instance and static things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you either use an object reference to an instance of `Generate`

in Unity you usually either get it via the Inspector using e.g.

```
// in the Inspector reference the according component via
// drag&drop the object to this field
public Generate GenerateReference;
```

or using [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) (if the component is attached to the same object)

```
var GenerateReference = GetComponent<Generate>();
```

or if it is on anothet object

```
var GenerateReference = anotherObjectReference.GetComponent<Generate>();
```

where ofcourse now you would have to get `anotherObjectReference` first.

than you would use `GenerateReference.seed`.

See also [Controlling GameObjects using components](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html)

---

or alternatively make `seed` a

```
public static int seed;
```

in order to convert it to a non-instanced member, a member of the type `Generate` itself and go on using `Generate.seed`. In simple words this way all `Generate` components kind of `share` the same `seed` value.